# label в форме yii2 заезжает за инпут

Tags: php, yii2

Только изучаю yii. При добавлении лейбла к форме, он заползает под инпут. Это исправляется только в css прикреплением класса к лейблу и маргинами, или есть еще какой-то вариант?
[image: вот такая херобора]

Comment: Можно в view/site/login.php поменять разметку этой формы, там используется сетка bootstrap

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался. Именно так. ))